# Aligning H tags side by side in rows and columns with CSS & jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm displaying multiple nested categories: State > Store Type > Stores list. All category titles are in an h2 tag. Right now, it's displaying the states one row at a time stacked on top of each other. I'm having trouble getting the states to be listed in 3 columns side by side because they're being controlled by jQuery as h2 tags which I can't change. I can turn the h2 tags to divs and float them but then the nested hierarchy breaks.

This is how it looks now:

http://screencast.com/t/Xkwp0CNE4AP1

http://screencast.com/t/WzrANEFtw

I'm trying to change the css to make it look like this.

http://screencast.com/t/WHoP9Zhnl3Y

Tried everything but it breaks the jQuery.

CSS

```
    .oestlstore {
    float:left;display: inline-block;width:20%;padding:15px;
  }

/* root element for accordion. decorated with rounded borders and gradient background image */
.accordion {
background:#000;
width: 99%;
padding-top:0px;
 -background:#666;


}

/* accordion header */
.accordion h2 {
background:#A91414;
margin:0;
padding:5px 15px;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
cursor:pointer;
color: #fff;
margin:15px;
padding-top:9px;
padding-bottom:9px;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;

}


/* accordion header */
.accordion2 h2 {
background:#000;

}


/* currently active header */
.accordion h2.current {
cursor:default;
background-color:#B40404;

}
/* currently active header */
.accordion2 h2.current {
cursor:default;
background-color:#000;

}

/* accordion pane */
.accordion .pane {
display:none;
padding:15px;
color:#fff;
font-size:16px;
}

/* a title inside pane */
.accordion .pane h3 {
font-weight:normal;
margin:0 0 -5px 0;
font-size:16px;
color:#999;
}
```

Jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

$(document).ready(function() {
//Initialising Accordion
$(".accordion").tabs(".pane", {
    tabs: '> h2',
    effect: 'slide',
    initialIndex: null
});

//The click to hide function
$(".accordion > h2").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass("current");
    } else if (!$(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }
});
});
//]]>  

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
<h2>New York</h2>
<div class="pane">
    <div class="accordion accordion2">
        <h2><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Whole-Foods-Market-    Logoa.png" alt="Whole Foods Market" /></h2>
        <div class="pane">

             <div class="oestlstore">
                Market 97th St<br />
                 808 Columbus Ave.<br />
               New York, NY 10025
               </div>

        </div>

 <h2 ><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/stopshopicon.jpg" alt="Stop & Shop" style="margin-top:10px;" /></h2>
        <div class="pane">
          test
        </div>

<h2><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ShopRiteicon.png" alt="ShopRite" /></h2>
        <div class="pane">
          test
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<h2>New Jersey</h2>
<div class="pane">
    content
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if im understanding you correctly you can get the red `h2` tabs to line up side by side by adding `display:inline` to the `.accordian h2` css

see below for details

```
.oestlstore {
    float:left;display: inline-block;width:20%;padding:15px;
}
.split{
    margin:25px;
}
/* root element for accordion. decorated with rounded borders and gradient background image */
.accordion {
    background:#000;
    width: 99%;
    padding:12px;
    -background:#666;
}

/* accordion header */
.accordion h2 {
    background:#A91414;
    padding:9px 15px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin:15px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:inline;
}


/* accordion header */
.accordion2 h2 {
    background:#000;
}


/* currently active header */
.accordion h2.current {
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#B40404;
}
/* currently active header */
.accordion2 h2.current {
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#000;
}

/* accordion pane */
.accordion .pane {
    display:none;
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
}

/* a title inside pane */
.accordion .pane h3 {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 -5px 0;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#999;
}
```

and a div that splits the layers to stop

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h2>New York</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>
    <h2>New Jersey</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>
    <h2>California</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>

    <div class="split"></div><!-- this is what you can use to split the levels -->

    <h2>New York</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>
    <h2>New Jersey</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>
    <h2>California</h2>
    <div class="pane">
        content
    </div>   
</div>
```

This is how it looks on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/ptx02urn/)

Comment: That works but then as I add more states they float over each other:http://screencast.com/t/caS1GDs0H

Comment: this is helpful! But this is what I get: http://screencast.com/t/yoNLEzpEqA Is there anyway to control the width so the columns are the same width like this? http://screencast.com/t/6NczExxP3VH

Comment: set a `width` for the .`accordian h2` rather than relying on `padding` to give it width either side of the word(s)

Comment: When i set a width it doesn't inherit it for some reason http://screencast.com/t/mdRsntDc http://jsfiddle.net/ptx02urn/2/

Comment: I think the only way to do it is by replacing the h2 tags with div's but then it breaks the jquery because the jquery uses h2 tages for the nesting.

Comment: it wont break the jquery you would just have to give the `div`s a class and use that class in the jquery instead of the `h2`s